# SQL Datetime Avg

Tags: sql, date, average

I am trying to get the avg total days between two dates using SQL.

My Table is as follows

```
intSalesPerson dtmDateSetup         dtmWelcomeLetterSent
1              2015-02-18 22:47:13.890  2015-03-19 19:53:04.153
1              2015-03-06 13:04:20.730  2015-03-19 19:55:29.800
1              2015-03-16 18:16:43.290  2015-03-19 19:55:25.690
```

My SQL query is something like this?

```
select avg([dtmDateSetup] - [dtmWelcomeLetterSent]) as avg_days
from [tblCustomer] where [intSalesPersonID] = 1 AND [dtmWelcomeLetterSent] IS NOT NULL
```

Result should be

```
Avg_days
15
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am asking what the business logic you want to apply to get Date Avg, Because right now your sample data and Output 3 does not seems any logic, Modify your question so that we can understand what exactly you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First calculate the days between each date (I'm assuming SQL Server):

```
select [dtmDateSetup], [dtmWelcomeLetterSent],
   DATEDIFF(day,dtmDateSetup,dtmWelcomeLetterSent)
from [tblCustomer]
where [intSalesPersonID] = 1 AND [dtmWelcomeLetterSent] IS NOT NULL
```

Then the average is easy:

```
select AVG(DATEDIFF(day,dtmDateSetup,dtmWelcomeLetterSent))
from [tblCustomer]
where [intSalesPersonID] = 1 AND [dtmWelcomeLetterSent] IS NOT NULL
```